# djConfig in XPages escapes values making the setting wrong

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-domino

I need to set extraLocale on djConfig on a Domino 8.5.3FP1 server.

(Package Explorer)

This is normally done like so:

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig=extraLocale: ['sv-se']
```

But Domino will escape my string into this:

```
extraLocale: [\'sv-se\']
```

Doesn't matter if I do:

```
xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig=extraLocale: ["sv-se"]
```

Same result.

Any ideas appreciated!

/J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here comes an evil hack for this problem (tested in IE 8 & 9 & FF 15,16,17):

1. Change your *extraLocale* to a javascript variable
2. Add a javascript block before everyhing else in the *beforePageLoad* event

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
       <xp:this.properties>
           <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig" value="extraLocale: exLocale" />
       </xp:this.properties>

       <xp:this.beforePageLoad>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:
           var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
           var response = exCon.getResponse();
           var writer = response.getWriter();
           writer.write("<script>\n");
           writer.write("var exLocale=['sv-se','de-de']\n");
           writer.write("</script>\n");
           }]]>
       </xp:this.beforePageLoad>


       <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1"
           value="dojo.addOnLoad( function(){ alert( dojo.config.extraLocale ) } );">
       </xp:scriptBlock>
   </xp:view>
   ```

In this example I added the paramter directly to the XPage and add two extra locales.
Hope this helps and/or inspires for a cleaner solution :-)

P.S.
The problem is that the additional *djConfig* parameters will be parsed internally and the slashes are escaped automatically.